# Troubleshooting PSQL localhost setup

Tags: postgresql

I’ve been working to set up a PostgreSQL localhost server to test my Ruby on Rails database on my machine. However, I keep encountering the same fatal error a lot of people seem to be receiving, though with no plausible solution as of yet. Here are the steps I took towards getting it running properly:

```
brew install postgres
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
psql -d postgres
```

But then I received the following error:

```
FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
```

To solve this, I used

```
killall postgres
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

to reset the database, which allowed me to initdb, but then I just received the same FATAL error.

This went in a loop multiple times, as I tried other variances to solve the problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled psql several times and restarted my computer. I read up on this error, and from what I learned it seems to be a permissions error. However, I am certain that I am running it off of the administrative account. None of the other suggested solutions seemed to work for me, in fact many of the steps taken above were from suggested forum posts. I tried this, too:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.heroku.postgres ~/Application Support/Postgres/
```

… but it didn’t work, either.

I’m running on Macintosh OSX 10.9.4, and the only other processes on my computer relating to PSQL are PGAdmin3, which I was planning to use to run the server, and redis, which is working just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but works fine on my machine: http://postgresapp.com

Comment: Errors about missing `global/pg_filenode.map` usually occur when the data directory or its contents are deleted while PostgreSQL is running. Something really not right is going on on your machine. OS X 10.9 seems to be a disaster for PostgreSQL in general, as it seems to like going around and "cleaning up" empty directories, among other things.

Comment: @CraigRinger How would you suggest going about doing that? I actually had a fully-functioning postgresql localhost up in June this year, but had to factory reset my computer recently. So I know it's possible to set one up on this machine and operating system.